# forgot login password working locally but not on live site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, postmark

once I push to heroku I cannot get the password reset to work.......using devise and postmark

my devise.rb file:

```
  config.mailer = "UserMailer" # mailerCLASS
```

development.rb /production.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :port           => '25',
  :address        => ENV['POSTMARK_SMTP_SERVER'],
  :user_name      => ENV['POSTMARK_API_KEY'],
  :password       => ENV['POSTMARK_API_KEY'],
  :domain         => 'agile-eyrie-1022.herokuapp.com',
  :authentication => :plain,
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

my user_mailer.rb

```
    class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

  default from: "default@mydomain.com"

  def reset_password_instructions(record, opts={})
       devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions)
     end
   end
```

Comment: username and password use the same key? `ENV['POSTMARK_API_KEY']`

Comment: that is what the postmark api docs advise me to do?